# SOLR: how to ignore 0 (zero) value in MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory processor?

Tags: solr

We have added custom price fields in another field "all_prices".

```
<processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="source">CustomPrice1</str>
  <str name="source">CustomPrice2</str>
  <str name="source">CustomPrice3</str>
  <str name="dest">all_prices</str>
</processor>
```

so, In solr, it looks like

```
"CustomPrice1":79.95,
"CustomPrice2":69.95,
"CustomPrice3":59.95,
"all_prices":[79.95,69.95,59.95],
```

So we added the processor "MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory" as below:

```
<processor class="solr.MinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory">
  <str name="fieldName">all_prices</str>
</processor>
```

Now, data in solr will be like below:

```
"CustomPrice1":79.95,
"CustomPrice2":69.95,
"CustomPrice3":59.95,
"all_prices":[59.95],
```

Now, In some cases when we have zero value in custom price like below:

```
"CustomPrice1":24.95,
"CustomPrice2":0.0,
"all_prices":[0.0],
```

So in that case, we just want to ignore the 0 (zero) value and take 2nd min value into all_price.
How to do this?

Comment: I think in this case you have to write your own custom class and implement the required logic...then you can use that class here

Comment: you have to write you own class by extending FieldValueSubsetUpdateProcessorFactory

Comment: Can you please explain with example how to achive this?

Comment: a similar procedure as explained here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387808/solr-copy-record-from-second-field-if-1st-field-is-null-or-not-available

Comment: Do you want me to share the code as well?

Comment: I'm trying with the new class creation.. But yes please share If possible? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if these are applied to each value (I'd think so, but you will need to try) , but you could possibly use a `RegexReplaceProcessor` that removes any zero values and then a `RemoveBlankFieldUpdateProcessor` that removes any empty strings .. only leaving those that you want to consider for your field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a class like below

```
package mysolr;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.solr.common.SolrException;
import org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore;
import org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.FieldNameSelector;

import static org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.ErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST;
import static org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.SELECT_NO_FIELDS;
    public final class SecondMinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory extends FieldValueSubsetUpdateProcessorFactory {
    
      @Override
      @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
      public Collection<Object> pickSubset(@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes"})Collection values) {
        @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes"})
        Collection result = values;
        try {
          Object[] array = values.toArray();
          Arrays.sort(array);
          Object res = (int)array[0] == 0 ? array[1] : array[0];
          result.clear();
          result.add(res);
  
         } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          throw new SolrException
            (BAD_REQUEST, 
             "Field values are not mutually comparable: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return result;
      }
    
      @Override
      public FieldNameSelector getDefaultSelector(SolrCore core) {
        return SELECT_NO_FIELDS;
      }
      
    }
```

With this code you need to create a jar named `"SecondMinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory .jar"`.

In the `solrConfig.xml`, please add the following changes.

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/plugins/" regex="SecondMinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory .jar" />

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:true}"
           processor="uuid,remove-blank,field-name-mutating,parse-boolean,parse-long,parse-double,parse-date,add-schema-fields">
    <processor class="mysolr.SecondMinFieldValueUpdateProcessorFactory "/>
    <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.DistributedUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Comment: I got error on this line "Collections.sort(result);" -- cast argument 'result' to 'List<T>'

Comment: I did not tested the code ...I will test and get back to you ob this...